# 2008 Chevy Cobalt SS: RPM struggles to go up and then it goes high

Tags: shifting, rpm, traction-control

My car has the "esn" light on, and I have a traction control button and it reads that it's off and I need to service esn traction.

I was wondering what that means. As for the rpm issue, I can hardly get above 890 RPM and then the car gets loud and the rpms go way higher than it should -- like in the 5000s.  So I'm not sure why my cars shifting like this; it has me worried and it is an automatic!

May someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take it and have the "ESN" light evaluated.  Most likely, the car thinks that one or more wheels is losing traction, and is supressing the engine RPM in order to regain the traction it thinks it doesn't have.

See if you can totally disable the traction control - this is the key.  If the current "off" state is not enough, you have to have whatever sensor is going bad replaced after the diagnosis.

Good Luck!

Comment: Today it doesn't wanna get up to speed and it is an automatic but when it shifts it julys the car! The engine lights on now to,thank you for ur time and advice!